# Custom Elements Using Pre-ES6 syntax

Tags: javascript, html

I'm trying to define a custom HTML tag in JavaScript called, say, 'hanz-franz'.
I want some function called 'pumpYouUp' to run when the browser's parser has finished looking at the sub-nodes and contents of my custom tag. I found this code online and have been using it for a while.

```
    class HTMLBaseElement extends HTMLElement {
            constructor() {
                const self = super();
                self.parsed = false; // guard to make it easy to do certain stuff only once
                self.parentNodes = [];
                return self;
            }

            setup() {
                // collect the parentNodes
                var el = this;
                while (el.parentNode) {
                    el = el.parentNode
                    this.parentNodes.push(el)
                }
                // check if the parser has already passed the end tag of the component
                // in which case this element, or one of its parents, should have a nextSibling
                // if not (no whitespace at all between tags and no nextElementSiblings either)
                // resort to DOMContentLoaded or load having triggered
                if ([this].concat(this.parentNodes).some(function(el){return el.nextSibling}) || document.readyState !== 'loading') {
                    this.childrenAvailableCallback();
                } else {
                    this.mutationObserver = new MutationObserver(function(){
                        if ([this].concat(this.parentNodes).some(function(el){return el.nextSibling}) || document.readyState !== 'loading') {
                            this.childrenAvailableCallback()
                            this.mutationObserver.disconnect()
                        }
                    });
                    this.mutationObserver.observe(this, {childList: true});
                }
            }
        }

        customElements.define("hanz-franz", class extends HTMLBaseElement {
            constructor() {
                const self = super();
                return self;
            }

            connectedCallback() {
                super.setup();
            }

            childrenAvailableCallback() { //this is the function that is run when the <hanz-franz> elements are loaded
                this.parsed = true;
                this.style.display = "none";
                pumpYouUp(this);
            }
        });
```

I've put a lot of work into making the rest of the program work in browsers all the way back to IE6, and I fully intend to make this code compatible with browsers the dinosaurs might have used as well. However, Babel isn't giving me anything useful. Because of how it implements classes in ES5 syntax, the `this` variable isn't referring to the same thing, and those classes apparently don't work with the custom elements API as shown by a few other SO questions who have asked similar (but distinct) questions. I'm curious about making this snippet of code compatible with ancient browsers that don't support the ES6 class syntax while still maintaining the ability to run the `pumpYouUp` function only when all children have been parsed. Is that even possible? I suspect the answer may boil down to how classes are actually implemented, how to emulate one closely enough to fool the customElements API into thinking it's dealing with a class, and then if all of this code is really necessary to monitor whether the children have been parsed. Can anybody help me find a solution to this problem? Thanks in advance.

** By the way, I know Edge, IE, and other browsers don't support the customElements API, but I'd like to not alienate any users. This is part of a much larger project that involves reaching as many users as possible and running on browsers that show up in web developers' nightmares. Thanks again!

Comment: Even https://github.com/WebReflection/document-register-element only goes back to IE 8. Supporting IE 6 is **not at all an option with regard to web components**.

Comment: @connexo That's fair. It was a bit of an exaggeration, but still, I'd like to go as far back as possible, and since classes are ES6 syntax, I'd like to not use them to register a custom element while still keeping the ability to run a certain function when all children have been loaded.

Comment: https://github.com/WebReflection/document-register-element#v1-caveat might help you overcome that. Also it only works with Babel 7.

Comment: Also https://github.com/WebReflection/html-parsed-element might be what you are looking for. A package I have helped creating. The code is based on the snippet you found and are using from a github issue where I suggested that code.

Comment: https://babeljs.io/docs/en/next/babel-plugin-transform-classes.html might also help shed some light on the issue.

Comment: Thanks for the link, @connexo. The section you pointed to still uses classes though, and like I mentioned in the question, Babel is creating a very complicated mess of functions and objects that doesn't let me keep the functionality of running `pumpYouUp` when the children have been parsed. Possibly if someone could explain how Babel's output for the above code works, and how to reintroduce that functionality in a different way.

Comment: I don't see any definition of `pumpYouUp` in your code. I don't know if the suggested stack works for browsers older than IE 11 (as I don't have access to any of those and they're by far out of scope for any professional product).

Comment: I didn't define it in the code above, but for the sake of argument, let's say `function pumpYouUp (reference_to_hanz_franz_element) {console.log("Children have been parsed")}`. It doesn't really matter what is in the function, just that it is being called when the children are parsed. Took a quick look at the package you created, it looks very interesting! Have you had success using Babel on it? Sidenote: This is a bit more than a professional product, it's a long story, but I'm trying to reach every possible user.

Comment: I didn't *create* the package, most of the work was done by @WebReflection. I just helped with it.

Comment: We fully avoided the problem by only defining the webcomponents when the DOM is already parsed, using `defer` on the including `script` tag. Alternatively you can also simply load your webcomponents right before `</body>` (for browsers that don't know `defer`). Note that in that case you still cannot rely on children being parsed if you're using `document.write` (which you shouldn't anyway!) to put your webcomponents in the DOM. Dynamic element creation and -insertion using `document.createElement` and `appendChild` works flawlessly then, also setting `innerHTML` works with no issues.

Comment: So the function has to be run when the children are finally parsed, as in, upon reading of the `</hanz-franz>' closing tag. It's a strange situation, but I need to essentially do work on the children of the tag before the next sibling element is parsed, so deferring until the end of the document wouldn't work.

Comment: I assume you have a conceptual problem here then.